# Coding in VSCode using Python: Library that's been downloaded by pip shows as nonexistent

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, libraries

I am working on a climatology study and need to use a particular library called typhon to perform some calculations with the data. However, whenever I run the code, it informs me that the typhon library cannot be imported because it does not exist.

I downloaded the typhon library to my computer using pip. It was in my Appdata file under my Python folder. I also tried moving it to the VSCode folder instead (that's where I'm using it) but neither worked. The rest of my libraries, which do work, are in the Appdata file.

Comment: Probably, the interpreter you are using in VSCode is not the same interpreter you used when you ran `pip install`. You generally shouldn't be moving around library files manually like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you using virtual interpreter or system interpreter
if you are using 1. system interpreter first try delete then reinstall it using python3 -m pip install typhon see if its working or not and 2. in rare cases if you have both system and virtual interpreter delete the virtual interpreter it sometime cause err.

it worked for me. see if it works for you or not

Answer (score 2):

In VS Code's terminal window, you can type `python3 -V` to check the python version.

Make sure this matches the version selected as kernel in the top right of VS Code.

Then type the following in the terminal:

`python3 -m pip install typhon`

This should ensure that the typhon library is installed for the version of python that is in the active session.

Hope this helps.

Note: you should also undo the directory move you described, it shouldn't be necessary to manually move library files around like that.

Comment: Another way is using shortcuts `Ctrl+Shift+P` and type "Python: Select Interpreter" to choose the interpreter which you installed the package in.

Comment: I did do it this way, but it didn't work. It turned out the issue was that I was using a virtual interpreter. After I deleted it, it worked again. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

I was using a virtual interpreter instead of a system interpreter by accident and the virtual interpreter did not have the typhon library. I deleted the virtual interpreter and that solved the issue.